# Google Cloud Dataflow finished succeeded with worker logs "Missing next work index in "

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

My dataflow job succeeded and generated correct output file.
But the worker log outputted a lot of error logs.
What after "Missing next work index in " is a large json.

```
2020-12-24T08:38:32.210ZMissing next work index in {"leaseExpireTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:01Z","reportStatusIn...
```

How can I fix the error?
And what does error mean?

Answer (score 2):

That error message is a red herring. The error is triggered when the system returns a Null index which happens in some cases. This does not affect the jobs and is just log spam. You shouldn't be concerned about it.

The Dataflow team has been working on fixing it on their end and submitted [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/13343) pull request that afaik should take care of the error in future Apache beam versions.

Comment: I am still getting this error now, when will the fix be deployed please?